# RxJava: Calling .subscribe() with same Observer for multiple Observables

Tags: java, rx-java

What is the behavior of the same Observer calling `.subscribe()` on several Observables?

Will they be implicitly merged?  Or is it that that last on wins?

For instance:

```
event1.subscribe(myObserver);
event2.subscribe(myObserver);
```

Comment: My instincts tell me it will be one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe(rx.functions.Action1)), as long as you don't [cancel](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Subscription.html#unsubscribe()) the `Subscription`s returned by each Observables, the observer will be subscribed *to all observables*.

I expect if you subscribe the same observer multiple times to one observable, you will be notified multiple times - otherwise the subscriptions made previously would "magically" go dead, which is something that may cause troubles.

```
// data members
Observable x, y;

void foo(Subscriber a) {
  // is subscriber a already registered with x?
  // Nevermind, I'm gonna make sure it is!
  Subscription s=x.subscribe(a);
  // provoke a change to be caught by 'a'

  // do some work based on whatever Subscriber 'a' captured.

  s.unsubscribe();
}

void bar() {
  Subscriber m;
  Subscription mx=x.subscribe(m);
  Subscription my=y.subscribe(m);

  // do something and then...
  foo(mx); // one would expect the mx subscription is still valid here!!!
  // do some more work

  my.unsubscribe();
  mx.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Does that imply that `onComplete` will be executed for each observable that's been added?

Comment: @mtyson I might be wrong, but yes, it will - that's the idea after all (I don't have an rx-java env handy for the moment to actually check it, but if my memory serves, this will be the behaviour)